# client server communication

Tags: wcf, client, client-server, communication, client-side

I am publically distributing an application which can be installed on users PC. Client will periodically communicate with the server to send information from the client. Server have to acknowledge the successful receipt of the information. Occasionally, server will do an one way communication with the client. My question is what is the best/failproof/recommended way to do client-server communication when client is massively distributed?  I am currently focusing on self-hosted service to do the communication. What precaution should i take if the clients ip address change frequently?

Comment: Sorry, what kind of information are you looking for?

Comment: @JohnSaunders ineed to send xml data from and to to the server

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions are:

- Use HTTP or HTTPS on default ports. By *massively* I understand you will have no control over the network restrictions, firewalls, NAT traversal, etc. Using HTTP(S) and initiating the connections from the clients with simple web requests will save you a lot of trouble.
- Use polling at regular/smart intervals to solve your *occasional* server initiated data transfer. Clients running on workstations wont have a public IP address, let alone a fixed one.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please explain what do you mean by polling at intervals?

Comment: I mean, every day (or every hour, or less, depending on your needs) your clients ask the server: 'hey!, are there any news?', that way your server can transmit what it has to, say without initiating a connection by itself.